# Exposed filters of a view printed in different places

Tags: 7, views

How can I get a view to expose filters that are drunk rendering separately.

Have three filters exposed but I do not know how to get it to fit the layout correctly.

Is it possible to achieve this type of layout with drupal 7?

I have an image that explains:

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be to create a custom template for that specific View. However, based on the screenshot, it looks like you only want to move 2 of the 3 exposed filters to the side.

Had you wanted to move all of the exposed filters to the side, it likely could have been done with a custom views-view.tpl.php file.

Perhaps give the  [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) a try!

I haven't personally tested this module, but a Google search lead me to this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in "exposed form settings" on third column in views ui, select: display as a block: yes, then configure the block in blocks admin page (or panels if you are usuing it) to display it in your page. [BEF](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module is a good one, try with and without it.